# How to analyze data in Excel

Tags: excel, analysis

I have an Excel document that consists of huge data in need of analysis.
The data is basically objects with corresponding error messages. Typical output is:

```
**REC NO07/121007163**
Valuation for 0001 IFRS16 Balance sheet valuation
Asset transactions already posted need to be reversed
The valuation could not be completed
**REC NO07/121007165**
Valuation for 0001 IFRS16 Balance sheet valuation
Asset transactions already posted need to be reversed
The valuation could not be completed
**REC NO07/121007220**
Valuation for 0001 IFRS16 Balance sheet valuation
Closing balance 5 070,00 NOK liability available
Difference 5 070,00- NOK between clearing and expense available
**REC NO07/121007221**
Valuation for 0001 IFRS16 Balance sheet valuation
Closing balance 5 070,00 NOK liability available
Difference 5 070,00- NOK between clearing and expense available
```

What you see in bold above, is the object. This is not in bold in Excel, but I have made it bold here to explain. Everything in-between is the error message for that object.

The length (number of lines) of the error message could vary between objects.

What I would like to do, is basically convert the above to this:

```
REC NO07/121007163  Valuation for 0001 IFRS16 Balance sheet valuation. Asset transactions already posted need to be reversed. The valuation could not be completed
REC NO07/121007165  Valuation for 0001 IFRS16 Balance sheet valuation. Asset transactions already posted need to be reversed. The valuation could not be completed
REC NO07/121007220  Valuation for 0001 IFRS16 Balance sheet valuation. Closing balance 5 070,00 NOK liability available. Difference 5 070,00- NOK between clearing and expense available
REC NO07/121007221  Valuation for 0001 IFRS16 Balance sheet valuation. Closing balance 5 070,00 NOK liability available. Difference 5 070,00- NOK between clearing and expense available
```

I am adding a tab between the object and the error message.

I am combining all lines of the error message with ". "

Is this possible in Excel and if yes, is there anyone that could help me with that?

Thank you

Best regards
Antonis

I have tried to do this with formulas in Excel but as the number of lines for each error message varies, I was not able to solve it.

Comment: Can we consider `REC` as a fixed prefix for all the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the error codes start with `REC` and no excel version constraints per tags listed in the question, then you can use the following formula in cell `B1`:

```
=LET(A, A1:A16, m, ROWS(A), seq, SEQUENCE(m), idx, FILTER(seq, (LEFT(A,3)="REC")),
 start, idx+1, end, VSTACK(DROP(idx-1,1), m), MAP(start, end, 
  LAMBDA(s,e, INDEX(A,s-1)&" "&TEXTJOIN(". ",, FILTER(A, (seq>=s) * (seq<=e))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

Basically, it finds first the index position of the error codes (`idx`) and based on that finds the `start` and `end` rows of each error message. Then we use `MAP` to concatenate the result via `TEXTJOIN` selecting on each iteration the range via `FILTER` and prefixing the error code (`INDEX(A,s-1)`).